# How can I use paged printing of data frames in bookdown, when Rmd files are first knitted and then merged?

Tags: r, dataframe, yaml, bookdown

**################################################**

Edit: A minimal reproducible example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tillschwoerer/bookdown-minimal).

**################################################**

I am using **bookdown** to combine a number of Rmd files into a gitbook. Specifically, I want to use the **"Knit and Merge" (K-M)** approach, described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html): Rmd files are knitted in separate R sessions, and merged afterwards. To do the K-M approach I have specified `new_session: yes` in the _bookdown.yml file.

The opposite would be the "Merge and Knit" approach (M-K), where the Rmd files are first merged and then knitted in a common R session. For several reasons, I don't want to use this approach.

**My problem:** I would like data frames to be printed in paged format, but this does not seem to work using the K-M apprach.

In case of the opposite M-K approach, this can be achieved by specifying `df_print: paged` in the YAML header of the index.Rmd file. My YAML header looks like this:

```
---
title: "My Book Title"
author: "My Name"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    df_print: paged
---
```

Where can/should I specify `df_print: paged` for bookdown's K-M approach?

Desired printing format of data frames:

[image: paged df printing]